How can I send data from my application to ESP32
I need to send slideable red, green and blue values of RGB LED to my Esp32 from a mobile application and I want to do it with arduino IDE. I am having trouble communicating with my Esp32 with the application. In the project, Esp32 should act like a modem and I need to connect to it as if it were a modem.
I tried SoftAP in the Arduino examples but I couldn't adapt it for myself. Unfortunately, Chatgptden can't help me with this.

"Esp32 should act like a modem" = a modem is a device with a cable - do you really want to make a cable driven connection to your ESP ? Why don't use Bluetooth or Wifi (ESP 32 setup as Access Point) ?

I am so sorry for my terrible explanation . Actually I will use Esp32 as Acces point. I have some issue sending Rgb value from app to esp32

The way it works is by creating as you've figured a AP (access point) so your ESP behaves like a hotspot and broadcasts it's own WiFi SSID
Then you need to make a web server on the esp that will serve a html page with whatever sliders, buttons, input fields etc that you need and in the server you specify "routes" with callback functions that will intercept the requests from the html page and you can then do something on the ESP with the values received.
Here is a post with a full example code for an ESP32/ESP8266 I've given to some guy esp webserver example It's for an input field but you can easily change it to a slider
(if you want to go the IoT Cloud route for ESP control you can also check the home page of that website there are also some video tutorials)
A common misconception is that you need third party libraries like the AsyncWebServer, you don't need anything as the espressif-idf has everything you would need and will run faster.

What do you mean by 'modem'? Do you want your ESP to act like a accesspoint to which your phone/app can connect?
The issue you would face is that your esp would not be providing internet so the phone would most probably switch to other available network or then mobile data.
If you're able to overcome this and if your phone allows it could be one solution.
Another solution could be to make ESP access point simulate a network that requires login to use it. This way your phone will not switch to another network.
A very popular ESP library is WiFiManager which uses the same trick to get wifi credentials everytime you might want to switch the network your device exists on.

First of all, thank you for your answer. My problem is to send the rgb value to esp because I need to use the mobile app designed by someone else. Do you have a solution for me to do this?
